# What is the difference between the 3 definitions?

Tags: c++

```
string var = "var";
string var2("var2");
string var3 = string("var3");
```

What is the difference between the 3 definitions?

Comment: This is a far more complex issue than you would  expect, and there are subtle differences between language versions. (You might be interested in `string var4 {"var4"};`, too.)

Answer (score 3):

##### C++11

First lets consider the statement:

```
string var3 = string("var3"); //2 possiblities here in C++11, explained below
```

For the above shown statement there are 2 possibilities in C++11.

1. A **temporary object** of type `std::string` is created using the **string literal** `"var3"` on the **right hand side**. Then, the copy/move constructor of `std::string` is used to construct the object named `var3` from that temporary.
2. In C++11, there is [**non-mandatory copy elison**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which means that implementations are allowed to elide the temporary on the right hand side. This means **instead of** creating a temporary on the right hand side and then using a copy/move constructor to construct `var3` from that temporary, implementations can just directly construct `var3` from `"var3"`.

The exact same explanation goes for the statement:

```
string var = "var";//same 2 possiblities here in C++11 as explained above
```

Now lets consider the statement:

```
string var2("var2"); // This is direct initialization in both C++11 and C++17. No possibility of creating temporary here in both C++11 and C++17
```

In the above statement, an object named `var2` is constructed using the **string literal** `"var2"` and a suitable `std::string`'s constructor. There is no temporary of any kind in this case.

So, the answer to your question *in C++11* is that there is a difference between the statements **only if** the temporary is not eluded.

##### C++17

In C++17, there is [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which means that in this case when we write:

```
string var3 = string("var3");// only 1 possibility here in C++17. No temporary can be created.
```

In the above statement, the language guarantees that

> No temporary on the right hand side is created. Instead, the object `var3` is created directly using the string literal `"var3"` and a suitable `std::string`'s constructor.

Same goes for the statement:

```
string var = "var"; //only 1 possibility in C++17. No temporary created in C++17 due to mandatory copy elison
```

Now lets consider the statement:

```
string var2("var2"); //This is direct initialization in both C++11 and C++17 and there is no possibility of creating temporary in both C++11 and C++17
```

In the above statement, an object named `var2` is constructed using the **string literal** `"var2"` and a suitable `std::string`'s constructor. There is no temporary of any kind in this case.

So the answer to your question *in C++17* is that there is **no difference** between the statements.

Answer (score 1):

With enabled *copy elision* (guaranteed here since C++17), they are the same. Without it, there are additional *move constructor* and *destructor* calls in the first and third cases.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/P5Er1a1Pb

Major compilers do apply copy elision by default, even with disabled optimizations (such as with `-O0` in case of GCC/Clang).

---

*Note:* I assume `string` stands for `std::string`. Generally, you need to check the initialization rules for different types of *initialization* (*direct*, *copy*, ...) to resolve the effects.